# SQL - Substring and select * at the same time

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlyog

I need to do a substring of a column, but also pull all of the columns when I do the select.  Below is the code that I am trying to use, however it isn't functioning correctly:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(column_c, 1, 11) AS dateMoved, *
                FROM prostock_movement_header 
                WHERE column_a = '74' 
                AND column_b = '1372' 
                AND dateMoved = '2019-02-23'
```

How do I  go about doing a `SELECT *` along with a `SUBSTRING() AS ALIAS`, in the same statement, so that I retrieve all of the columns along with the ALIAS column.

Or is the only way to manually select every other column by name from the table?

Thanks

Comment: You can't refer to an aliased column in a where statement. You can use a subselect or change the dateMoved reference to its complete definition (substring fn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the order of the selection

```
SELECT *,SUBSTRING(column_c, 1, 11) AS dateMoved
                FROM prostock_movement_header 
                WHERE column_a = '74' 
                AND column_b = '1372' 
                AND SUBSTRING(column_c, 1, 11) = '2019-02-23'
```